# The file upload speed in phpMyAdmin seems to be very slow. How can I upload files to server faster?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

The file's `upload speed in phpMyAdmin` seems to be very slow. How can I upload files to server faster? I tried to increase `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` in **apache config/php.ini** but did not fix the problem.

Comment: Can you exclude your bandwidth as a factor? Can you upload stuff to other sites fast?

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version?

Comment: Files uploaded on another computer in 15 minutes but were not uploaded to this computer in 4 hours

Comment: 5.2.0 version @MarcDelisle

Comment: phpMyAdmin version 5.2.0 does not exist; the latest one is 4.7.3.

Answer (score 1):

**upload_max_filesize** is the limit of any single file. **post_max_size** is the limit of the entire body of the request so increasing that limits would not affect in upload speed. you should check your server memory status or process list. optimize server resource might help you.